# how to get food product data from barcode

Tags: iphone

I am able to read the barocode but i am confused about how to get the food product value from the barcode value .
Do we need to call a webservice or create a database locally ...
help me out
thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Free database here:

http://www.upcdatabase.com

and here:

http://www.yoopsie.com/

Otherwise just Google for "upc database" and you'll find people offering to sell you one.

I doubt that the databases will include prices since those are for the individual retailers to set.

Answer (score 13):

Have a look at [OpenFoodFacts](http://openfoodfacts.org/). It's a database that does just that, with ingredients, calories, etc. It's based on the barcode.

Answer (score 9):

In case anyone else is looking for this info in 2021, you can get this data directly from [the USDA's Food Data Central API](https://fdc.nal.usda.gov/api-guide.html), which is public domain. One of their endpoints has a `query` param, which supports keywords and, as a little tinkering revealed, UPCs! For instance, here's a query for a snack I had laying around:

https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/foods/search?query=850126007120&pageSize=10&api_key=DEMO_KEY

API keys can be had with an email address. Hope this is useful to someone!

Answer (score 8):

Product bar-codes contain almost no product related information - they are mere unique identifiers. The system used in Europe - EAN13 - consists of a country code, a manufacturer code, a product code, and a check digit. To translate any of this data into usable information you need a database or web-service.

Answer (score 6):

I know this was asked a long time ago but I figured I would give an update for anyone looking now...  We use an API called upcFood ([www.upcfood.com](https://www.upcfood.com)) They offer a simple API that allows lookup of food products directly from the barcode. upcFood includes nutrition data, Products Data, allergy data, ingredients etc. from a single search.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you still need the information since it is dated a year..

A french startup has created an application that can find most of the correspondant of ean-code to food product. It provides as well an API for developper to integrate in their application.

You can check it at : http://prixing.fr/api

Since it is based in France, it is in French language .. if it is useful, I hope it can help

Comment: The link doesn't exist anymore